# Problem with adding a new column to QSortFilterProxyModel: columns shift

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, model, qsortfilterproxymodel, qt5.15

I'm trying to add a column to a proxy model.

Long story short, I'm adding a column in an overloaded `setSourceModel` method with an `QSortFilterProxyModel::insertColumn()` method.

.h

```
class CompoundItemsTableModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CompoundItemsTableModel(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    void setSourceModel(QAbstractItemModel* sourceModel) override;
}
```

.cpp

```
void CompoundItemsTableModel::setSourceModel(QAbstractItemModel* sourceModel)
{
   QSortFilterProxyModel::setSourceModel(sourceModel);

   beginInsertColumns(QModelIndex(), 3, 3);
   QSortFilterProxyModel::insertColumn(3);
   endInsertColumns();
}
```

Then we use this model in a table:

.h

```
class VisibleTable : public QTableView {
public:
    explicit VisibleTable(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
```

.cpp

```
VisibleTable::VisibleTable(QWidget* parent)
    : QTableView(parent)
{      
    auto* proxyModel = new Database::CompoundItemsTableModel(this);
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(
        Database::SqLiteModel::initializeModel());
    setModel(proxyModel);
}
```

**Result:**
with any input all cells in the edited row to the right of the column are shifted one cell left.

[image]

**What I found out:**

1. `QSortFilterProxyModel::data` shows different values before and after any change. If I disable `QSortFilterProxyModel::setData()` it doesn't shift. But of course, it doesn't set data.  `setData()` surely sends a signal.
2. Delegates shift as well. If I input after the row has shifted, it will be inserted correctly into the SQL
3. Certainly, a shift occurs *after* the column that was added, not before.

**UPD 1:** The shift is triggered by `QTableView::commitData(editor);`, so sa soon as it works, the row is redrawn with a shift.

**UPD 2:** I've tried adding a column to the model, in my case it's `QSqlRelationalTableModel`.

```
    auto* model { new QSqlRelationalTableModel };

    model->setTable("table");
    model->select();
    model->insertColumn(0);
```

**Result:** the same, see pic:

[image]

**UPD 3:** I've tried doing the same with the underlying `QSqlRelationalTableModel`, and it proved to be unsuccessful. Entirelly the same effect.

Comment: QSortFilterProxyModel is for sorting and filtering (as the name says) and not for adding an additional column. All stuff inside the QSFPM expects that the column count  does not change. Add the column in your source model.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried. See `UPD 2` above. It didn't work.

Comment: My source model is `QSqlRelationalTableModel`. This means, after the last change, I have to add a column to the database or to change the model to writing a manual query with something. The latter seems to be a bad idea after the UPD 2. My DB is SQLite. It doesn't have "date" designation, so I made it by three integers day-month-year. So here, I want to merge these three integers together, and would refrain from adding another column to SQLite DB. Also, I don't want to substitute any of the fields.

Comment: Nobody keeps you from deriving from QSqlRelationalTableModel and adding the column there.

Comment: @chehrlic Thanks for the suggestion. It took me a while to get back to work. I've overloaded QSqlRelationalTableModel and added the methods. The result is 100% the same as with the proxy model I did: ti shows the data with a shift before or after a cell is touched. Even a simple model->insertColumn() called from my overloaded tableView makes this behavior.